# Iphone - how to programmatically answer a call

Tags: iphone

I saw this application on Cydia ( forgot the name) that will answer/ reject a call when you shake the phone.
Any ideea how is it done ? Couldn't find anything in SDK.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it'll be in the SDK for sure. Apple wouldn't include it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not somethhing that you can do using the official SDK. If you want to do this, it'll be using an undocumented/private API that Apple will not allow through their review.

If you want to be able to sell your application on the App Store, then you're going to have to let go of this idea. Else, you're going to have to resort to other means to find out how to do it.

Nothing personal, but I'm against jailbreaking, so I can't help you.